# C++ Is it possible to have dynamic default data members

Tags: c++, overloading, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

I'd like to make an Image class that can overload array access operators, so you can do something like:

```
Image<unsigned long> img(100, 100); // an image 100x100
unsigned long middlePixel = img[50][50]; // access at (50,50)
```

In order to allow for the second array access operator, I've had to return a 'proxy' struct which again has another array access operator overload.

(In Image class):

```
inline auto operator[] (int x)
{
  struct
  {
    T *col;

    inline T operator[] (int y) { return col[y]; }
  } proxy{ raster[x] };
  return proxy;
}
```

This solution is currently working; however, it exposes the image column 'col' as a public member of the anonymous struct. I'd like to make this an anonymous class so that 'col' is private (or make the member itself private in the struct).

The problem is that I am unsure then how to initialize 'col'. I realize I can also set 'col' with a setter function in the anonymous struct, but I'd like to make an anonymous struct that only has array access overloading exposed.

I was hoping to be able to accomplish something like this instead (ofc does not compile):

```
inline auto operator[] (int x)
{
  class
  {
    T *col = raster[x];
  public:
    inline T operator[] (int y) { return col[y]; }
  } proxy;
  return proxy;
}
```

Is such a solution possible without having to name my struct?

Reference Code:

```
template <class T = unsigned long>
class Image
{
private:
  int width, height;
  T **raster;
public:
  Image(const int width, const int height) : width(width), height(height)
  {
    raster = new T*[height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
      raster[y] = new T[width];
  }

  ~Image()
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
      delete[] raster[y];
    delete[] raster;
  }

  inline auto operator[] (int x)
  {
    struct
    {
      T *col;

      inline T operator[] (int y) { return col[y]; }
    } proxy{ raster[x] };
    return proxy;
  }
};
```

Edit (Solution using named struct):

```
inline auto operator[] (int x)
{
  class Col
  {
    T *col;
  public:
    Col(T *col) : col(col) {};
    inline T operator[] (int y) { return col[y]; }
  };
  return Col(raster[x]);
}
```

Comment: why you dont want to name the proxy? just give it a name, make `col` private and write a constructor to initialize it. Maybe i miss something, but I dont see the problem

Comment: @user463035818 I don't know why I missed that. Kind of tunnel visioned on anonymous structs/classes. That solves my immediate problem, though I am still curious if you can set default members of a class/struct dynamically.

Comment: i have the feeling that you are trying hard to hide the proxy from the user. I would actually advice you to do the opposite, anyhow you cannot prevent someone from doing `decltype(img[50])` to see what it is

Comment: btw to my experience sometimes the better alternative is to give up on the square brackets and use a `img.getPixel(50,50);` instead

Comment: @user463035818 Hm that is true. I wanted to make it an anonymous struct so users could not 'inspect' what type it is, but there is a valid point that you can just do decltype now. On top of that making it anonymous or not doesn't offer me anything. (So yes I am trying too hard haha).